# How to disable sniffing of elasticsearch in Monstache

Tags: mongodb, go, elasticsearch, monstache

I'm getting this error while using Monstache:

```
Unable to create Elasticsearch client: health check timeout: no Elasticsearch node available
```

I applied these lines to Monstache configuration:

```
elasticsearch-validate-pem-file = false
elasticsearch-healthcheck-timeout-startup = 200
elasticsearch-healthcheck-timeout = 200
```

However, I still encounter the mentioned error. When I searched about it, I found that the problem is due to sniffing in elasticsearch client. But I don't know where and how exactly I must change it?

I should denote that I studied [this tutorial](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/wiki/Connection-Problems) for this problem, but I'm still full of ambiguities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved when I installed Monstache on the same local server on which the ELK stack was installed. Also, the MongoDB database on the remote server has been changed to a single node replica set to be able to connect to Monstache.

Answer (score -1):

let's try to use

```
elastic.SetSniff(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already did it. But it doesn't work.

Comment: did you tried to config url connect?
url := "http://[host]:9200" 
(not include the slash "/" at the end of url)

ref: https://github.com/rwynn/monstache/issues/250

Comment: Yes, I did. But the problem did not solve.